# Spring: Value Injection for Library Code Fails

Tags: java, spring

I have a library class that needs a value injection:

```
@Value("${env}")
private String env;
```

In my server application which uses this library, I have the `config.properties` file under resources folder, it contains `env=dev`. And in my `ui.xml` I have:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>

<bean id="libraryBeanId" class="path.to.the.library.class" >
</bean>
```

However, I always get `Could not resolve placeholder for ${env}`. But when I use command line option `-Denv=dev` to start the server app, the value gets injected correctly.

My project structure is like:

```
App:
  - src:
  - main:
      - java
      - resources:
          config.properties
          ui.xml
```

What's the difference of those 2 approaches and why the `xml` way doesn't work?

Comment: you're missing the `$` sign. Is that on purpose? Should be `@Value("${env}")`

Comment: @DanielBubenheim oh, I missed it here. But I have it in my code.  Edited it.  Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Did you already make it work or does the problem still exist? For me the given information seem to be correct so I would be interested in the solution.

Comment: @DanielBubenheim  no, it's not working. I had to change a way.